# My JS Code Isn't working on initial load / page change

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an external plugin and I included their JS in my custom.js. They are working fine until I access the page from another page (initial load). After I refreshed the page, then JS start working.

What really the problem, anyone has a suggestion?

```
$(document).ready(function(){                  
    function init_template(){
        ... (Another JS)

        //Trumbowyg WYSIWYG Editor
        $('.js-trumbowyg').trumbowyg({
            btns: [
                ['strong', 'em'],
                ['justifyLeft', 'justifyCenter'],
                ['unorderedList','link']
            ]
        });

        //Select2
        $('.js-select2').select2();
        $(".js-example-placeholder-single").select2({
            placeholder: "Pilih Produk",
            allowClear: true
        });

        //Filepond
        const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
        const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement );
        }
});
```

The Full JS Code
https://jmp.sh/V98Ytc9 (Start from line 1454)

I called them like this in my html

```
<div class="content bottom-25">
     <!-- Select2 -->
     <select class="js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control">
        <option></option>
        <option value="iOS">iOS</option>
        <option value="Linux">Linux</option>
        <option value="MacOS">MacOS</option>
        <option value="Android">Android</option>
        <option value="Windows">Windows</option>
     </select>

     <!-- WYSIWYG Editor Using Trumbowyg -->
     <textarea class="js-trumbowyg" placeholder="Ceritakan reviewmu secara menarik"></textarea>

      <!-- Filepond FIle Uploader-->
      <input type="file">
</div>
```

Full HTML Code https://jmp.sh/wPgiHCB

Maybe some picture can help

Initial Load
https://jumpshare.com/v/h8uw9pTUSlJScQa9CxlD

After Refresh
https://jumpshare.com/v/eh5iGDfjVKObYIWczWav

Comment: I believe that the script runs before the document has finished rendering. Try adding 'defer' in your html <script> tag. In addition, try to check if there is a "stronger" event listener than "ready".

Comment: There isn't much point declaring a function inside `ready`. Ready is designed to hook up jquery code once the dom is loaded. Where do you actually call `init_template`? We need a [mcve](in the question) here

Comment: Can you show where and how you have included the script tag and when do you call init_template function?

Comment: How is that relevant @fiveelements?

Comment: So I really a newbie here, the reason I included em inside $(document).ready(function(){                  
    function init_template(){ 
Because the template builder asked me to include every additional JS there. 
One of the JS code start working when I move inside there, but these 3 not.

Comment: Are you actually calling `init_template()`?

Comment: Maybe read [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED] Fixed by calling related plugin script and css file in every single page linked to this problem page.

Sorry for the noob experience

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to sort your scripts like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="trumbowyg/dist/trumbowyg.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js" async></script>
```

Load Custom.js at the end. becoz it contains function call which is in other js(like .trumbowyg(..) is trumbowyg.min.js).

Comment: Tried this but no change sir, I also tried to remove that async, or add async to all of them but still same result. But thanks for your suggestion

Comment: have you tried to clear cache and refresh after this change??

Comment: Yes, I tried it also in Firefox, Incognito haha. And also I hard refreshed everytime i change the code (Shift + F5)